# How to add code highlight to WebStorm?

Tags: coldfusion, webstorm

I have to work on a project that uses ColdFusion, and I would like to know if there is away that I can add code highlight and code suggestion for ColdFusion.

Is there a way that I create my own?

Answer (score 1):

Get [CFEclipse](http://cfeclipse.org/index.cfm/download/). This will provide code highlighting and a certain amount of autocompletion.

You can also trial Adobe's [CFBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-builder.html), but in my experience it's about equivalent.